# How to make a jQuery tooltip working in a content-script for a Google Chrome Extension for XML pages?

Tags: jquery, xml, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jquery-tooltip

I am creating a Google Chrome Extension that works for XML pages being opened in Chrome. Now I want a jQuery tooltip on this XML page.

The problem is that when I included a jQuery tooltip plugin and called the corresponding tooltip function in my content script, it DOES NOT show up for XML pages. It works for HTML pages but not for XML.

It shows an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null

Please tell me how to get tooltips working for XMl pages in a content-script..

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Tooltip needs to create a div in html page, it can't create it in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible to do without breaking the XML file - you will need to create an actual "DOM" for your tooltips.